# Dynamic Progress Bar - Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Since I am new to Vue and JS. I have some difficulties to making dynamic progress bar. This bar is kind of  indication of how many quiz already take. according to he photo below.

[image]

Below is my CSS and HTML of creating bar.

```css
.progressbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 1em auto;
    transition: width 500ms;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="progressbar">
  <div class="progressbar text-center" 
       style="background-color: green; margin: 0; color: white;"
       :style="{width: progress + '%'}">
    {{ progress }} 
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I make it increase?

Comment: What is the issue? Update `progress` to be the result of `total steps / completed steps`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy , Yes

Answer (score 0):

Place `progress` into the `data` and its working for me:

```
data() {
    return {
      progress: 70,
    }
  }
```

If you don't know how to calculate the progress just do it like so:

```
methods: {
  updateProgres() {
    this.progress=completedSteps/totalSteps*100
  }
}
```